# Can not change button height in navbar bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have an issue with changing button height in navbar.
 
Here is what I **want** : http://bit.ly/1NTJ4UE
 and here's what I **get** : 
http://bit.ly/19hlu4E
 I tried to play with padding and marging but it gets even worse. Can anybody show an example how to do what I want?
Here's piece of code I use :

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="icons/logo_footer_42x57.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deposit</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Withdrawal</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav group" styles="border: 1px solid #479ccf;">
          <li><a href="">Log in</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>            

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

my css file:

```
.divider-vertical {  
    height: 25px;  
    margin: 12px 0px 5px;  
    border-left: 1px solid #333;  
    border-right: 1px solid #479ccf;  
}  

nav a {  
    list-style-type: none;  
    display: inline;  
}  
ul.nav.navbar-nav.group {  
    border: 1px solid #479ccf;  
}
```

Comment: Please provide your CSS also.

Comment: try playing with line-height for the text and vertical-align to align with the divider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best option because one of the css rules uses !important.

I made 1 additional css class `user` for Login and Sign Up

The HTML change

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav group" styles="border: 1px solid #479ccf;">
   <li><a href="" class="user">Log in</a></li>
   <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
   <li><a href="" class="user">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

Change divider line height and margin

```
.divider-vertical {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 7px 0px 5px;
}
```

Added margin to the top of the group of links

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.group {
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

The new class to reduce the padding of the text

```
.user {
    padding: 5px 15px !important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pvqLh693/)